# Problem with mp3 audio caching on mobile iOS devices (both mobile Chrome and Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit

Cannot autoplay previously cached mp3 audio on mobile ioS (safari and chrome)

I'm developing an app in Angular 8 where in part of the app i'm trying to cache a couple of incoming audio mp3s in an array of objects and then either autoplay it or play it based on user action. Unfortunately it works everywhere (on desktop and Android ) exept for in mobile iOS devices . The cached audio simply doesnt play at times

basically for each  array  of a couple of objects received from API i run a for each loop caching mp3s in this array.

```
items.forEach(item => {
       const audio = new Audio();
       audio.src = urlString;
}
```

however if i disable caching and hit API each time i want to play the sound on mobile iOS devices everything works smootly as it should.

any idea how to solve this ?

enable mobile iOS audio caching

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a recent update from iOS (https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)

I had a similar issue, in which I received a small amount of the audio files every few clicks and cached them on demand-- even though technically this seemed like it was being generated by user interaction (each press of a button generated a new array of files to cache) it was not auto-playing most of the time.

My solution to this for iOS was to have a function execute on the first button pressed (such as a start / log in button) that cached every audio file that may be used throughout the entire application.

My autoplay worked fine after doing this, although it is a bit of a work around.